# Grid coming in Google Maps Android Tutorial

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know a similar question had been put up here earlier, but sadly I have tried that too.

I have given 
"keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\path to .android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android"
The generated fingerprint to http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html, then a generated API key to main.xml.

In AndriodManifest.xml, under manifest "Internet permission" line and under Application 
 
uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
has been put up.

3G icon is also active on the emulator.

But still **grids** are coming instead of a map. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid API key and internet permissions enabled in your manifest file, then you need to check to make sure that your emulator's network connection is active.

Try adding some error handling in your app to see where it's failing.